# Cordova CLI, using Git, and saving plugins/platforms

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, cordova-3, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to figure out how to reconcile some Cordova + git "best practices" with what I think is reality, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this for me.

If I understand correctly, the current "best practice" is to add these directories to my .gitignore (from the book "Developing with Cordova CLI", the current version):

```
platforms/
plugins/
node_modules/
```

This removes the easily downloadable plugins and mostly boilerplate platform code from version control because it can be easily generated with a simple Cordova CLI command.

But, this seems counter-intuitive because - and I'm thinking like NPM or Bower - with the Cordova CLI I can't save which platforms and plugins I'm using in a config file. With NPM, I can add a `--save` switch to save the package in the `package.json` file. This allows me to not version control my node_modules folder and instead use 'npm install'. With the Cordova CLI I can't seem to use the `--save` switch (is there an equivalent) to 'remember' the plugins or platforms I intend to use.

It seems that the `config.xml` file in the `www/` directory doesn't save which platforms or plugins have been added.

Is there some other file in the project that keeps a memory of which platforms and plugins I want to use? How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Cordova 4.3.0 + allows you to save and restore platforms and plugins. Saved information is stored in *config.xml* file. See [v5.0.0 release notes](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) and [the official Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/platform_plugin_versioning_ref_index.md.html).

You can save platforms and plugins using the `--save` option when you add them:

```
cordova platforms add PLATFORM --save
cordova plugins add PLUGIN --save
```

Or you can save platforms and plugins that are currently added:

```
cordova platforms save
cordova plugins save
```

By doing this there is no need to check in platforms or plugins into your code repository. They will be automatically restored based on your *config.xml* file when `cordova prepare` command is run.

Answer (score 2):

I typically write a hook to capture the plugins I want to use in my project.  You can see this in an article I wrote here: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

> With the new modular architecture of Cordova 3.x, every app needs plugins, even to use basic functionality such as logging or geolocation. Rather than document which plugins/features your project needs and ask each new developer to install them, download and install them automatically with a hook in the after_platform_add step. Using this plugin, every time a developer checks out the project and adds a platform, they automatically have the required plugins.

You also may be interested in following along with this bug, which suggests npm style --save functionality: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5775

Platforms are a little more difficult because they don't fit into the hook architecture, but you could write a shell script which you could execute to add your platforms.

```
#!/bin/sh
for plat in ios android; do
   cordova platform add $plat
done
```

You could do something similar with the version of cordova you have installed in node_modules (at least that is what I think you are installing in node_modules)--have shell script to get the correct version of cordova:

```
#!/bin/sh
VERSION=3.3.1-0.4.2
npm install cordova@$VERSION
```

PS Glad you liked the book!

Comment: Thanks! The hook sort of works. I get an error when running the command `cordova platform add android` on Windows 7. 

Running command: cmd args=["/c","C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","C:\\path\\Dev\\GitHub\\app\\.cordova\\hook
s\\before_platform_ls\\010_install_plugins.js","C:\\path\\Dev\\GitHub\\app"]
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Hook failed with error code 1: node

However, I can run the .js file directly with just `node \path\to\hook.js` and there is no error. I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: It looks, at first blush, like the command line interpreter doesn't like that space in 'Program Files' when it is trying to execute node.  I would try to install node.js in c:\node or something like that and see if you still get that error.