# development workflow for managing cordova plugins in your phonegap project

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm trying to compile a phonegap based app using different development machines - think multiple developers with their own machines and/or different machines to build different platforms.

The application was first compiled on PC for android which works ok, but when I try compile on Mac for ios, some of the app functionality is missing. I can confirm that other applications are able to be built on the same Mac for ios, so it's not an xcode related issue.

My `.gitignore` includes things like `node_modules/`, `www/`, `platforms/`, `app/lib` and `plugins/` and when I run `npm install` node_modules gets populated, and when I run `bower install` app/lib/ gets populated and so on.

As [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615677/error-current-working-directory-is-not-a-cordova-based-project/23152577#comment44226895_23152577) I then proceed with manually creating directories `www/`, `platforms/` and `plugins/` which then allows me to run `grunt platform:add:ios`. I can then emulate and/or deploy successfully, but when testing, functionality in the app is missing.

The problem seems to be that the `plugins/` folder doesn't get populated. I can manually run `cordova plugin add <plugin>` for each cordova plugin and when building and deploying the missing functionality shows up but the process seems a bit inefficient and prone to error if someone forgets to add a plugin.

Various guides have suggested running `cordova prepare ios` but this doesn't seem to do much.

This [blog post by Josh Bavari](http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/24/managing-cordova-plugins-with-package-dot-json-and-hooks/) suggests some hacking around to automate the process, and [this post talks about something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791323/cordova-cli-using-git-and-saving-plugins-platforms) but they're half a year old now.

Am I missing something obvious here, or is the manual `cordova plugin add` process a normal part of dev workflow? Cheers.